# How to simplify listing of dependencies in make file

Tags: makefile, latex

**Goal**

I am trying to use a Make file to automate the generation of a panel figure. The data and figures are generated from Rscripts and subsequently combined using latex to generate a PDF.

**Problem description**

Let's say, I would like to generate a panel figure consisting of 4 subfigures, arranged in a 2x2 grid. By using the following make file, I am able to generate the data as well as the subfigures:

```
all : data/plot1.txt plots/plot1.pdf \
data/plot2.txt plots/plot2.pdf \
data/plot3.txt plots/plot3.pdf \
data/plot4.txt plots/plot4.pdf \
plots/figure_5.pdf

#Panel Figure#

#Plot 1
data/plot1.txt : scripts/plot1_sim.R
    Rscript scripts/plot1_sim.R $@

plots/plot1.pdf : scripts/plot1_sim.R data/plot1.txt
    Rscript scripts/plot1.R $@

#Plot 2
data/plot2.txt : scripts/plot2_sim.R
    Rscript scripts/plot2_sim.R $@

plots/plot2.pdf : scripts/plot2_sim.R data/plot2.txt
    Rscript scripts/plot2.R $@

#Plot 3
data/plot3.txt : scripts/plot3_sim.R
    Rscript scripts/plot3_sim.R $@

plots/plot3.pdf : scripts/plot3_sim.R data/plot3.txt
    Rscript scripts/plot3.R $@

#Plot 4
data/plot4.txt : scripts/plot4_sim.R
    Rscript scripts/plot4_sim.R $@

plots/plot4.pdf : scripts/plot4_sim.R data/plot4.txt
    Rscript scripts/plot4.R $@
```

Using a latex file, e.g. `figure.tex` I am able to compile a panel figure as desired.

However, now I would like to add the construction of the final PDF by latex to the make file. This file is, of course, dependent on `plots/plot1.pdf` up to and including `plots/plot4.pdf`.

I added it to the code like this:

```
plots/figure.pdf : scripts/figure.tex plots/plot1.pdf plots/plot2.pdf plots/plot3.pdf plots/plot4.pdf
    pdflatex scripts/figure.tex
```

With four subfigures it is doable (but maybe ugly) to do it like this, but if you generate a panel figure with e.g. 16 subfigures, the code becomes unreadable.

**Question**

Is there a better way to include a larger list of dependencies, in this case for generating panel figures using make and latex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you could probably factorize all this with something like:

```
SIMRS    := $(wildcard scripts/plot*_sim.R)
PLOTS    := $(patsubst scripts/plot%_sim.R,%,$(SIMRS))
PDFPLOTS := $(patsubst %,plots/plot%.pdf,$(PLOTS))
TXTPLOTS := $(patsubst %,data/plot%.txt,$(PLOTS))

.PHONY: all

all: $(TXTPLOTS) $(PDFPLOTS) plots/figure_5.pdf

data/plot%.txt : scripts/plot%_sim.R
    Rscript $< $@

plots/plot%.pdf : scripts/plot%_sim.R data/plot%.txt
    Rscript scripts/plot$*.R $@

plots/figure.pdf: scripts/figure.tex $(PDFPLOTS)
    pdflatex $<
```

Note that the `plots/plot%.pdf: ...` pattern rule looks strange: its recipe uses `scripts/plotX.R` but its prerequisites are `scripts/plotX_sim.R` and `data/plotX.txt` (no `scripts/plotX.R`). Is it normal?